# can i run windows phone 7.1 app into windows 8 pro desktop/tablet?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-7.1

We have developed an app for windows phone using windows phone 7.1 SDK. Now client is asking if we can run the same app in Windows 8 Pro Desktop/Tablet or not.

I am struggling to find out any help on this but not getting any luck.

Anybody is there can help me out on this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.  Nor can you run a Windows Phone 8 app on a Windows tablet (of any flavour).

Comment: Thanks Jon B for your answer... do i need to create separate app for Windows 8 pro tablet/desktop?

Comment: If you're creating a "Windows Store" (previously known as "metro", and sometimes called a "WinRT") app it will run on Windows Pro desktops and tablets and also WinRT tablets.  You won't find the experience of writing that too different.  Learn how over at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/default.aspx

Comment: Many thanks Jon B for provide me help on this. I will look into.